# Python Script much slower outside of Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, performance, compilation

I have a python script to calculate the first 1M numbers of the Fibonacci Sequence. The Script takes ~6s to run when I run it from Visual Studio.

But when I start the Script directly it will take over 100s.
I tried Compiling the Script but that didn't change anything.

What exactly is causing that and how can I get the same speed outside Visual Studio?

Comment: Which python iplementation is used by your Visual Studio? It could be an entirely different one than what you execute manually...

Comment: @guidot good point. I'm using 3.7 in Visual Studio and 3.8.2 when I start it directly but i don't think this could be causing such a difference.

Comment: There really isn't enough details to tell, I suppose you need to profile the execution on your setup and see where it spends the time.